# Is there a way to differentiate between a Jinn using its ability and a ghost interacting with a power box?

Tags: phasmophobia

While playing a round of Phasmophobia, I discovered that the ghost room was the room with the power box. While investigating, I noticed that I had an EMF on the power box. This could be a sign that it is a Jinn using its ability, but the ghost can also interact with the door on the power box. This results in an EMF in about the same location.

Is there a way I can rule out if the ghost interacted with the power box itself, rather than the door to the power box, without running back to the car to check sanity while the ghost room is the room with the power box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a ghost to interact with the door of the [fuse box](https://phasmophobia.fandom.com/wiki/Fuse_Box), the ghost has to be nearby the breaker. Generally speaking, this means within the same room as the breaker, or on the other side of the wall of the breaker. Using motion sensors near the door of the room with the breaker, you should be able to determine if the ghost is within that room or not.

For a [Jinn](https://phasmophobia.fandom.com/wiki/Jinn) to leave an EMF reading at the breaker when using its ability, the breaker must be on (Jinn cannot use abilities if breaker is off or broken), and the Jinn must be in the same room or within 3m of a player.

Therefore, if the breaker is off and you get an EMF reading on the box doesn't change the breaker state (if it turns the breaker on, it might be a Jinn, but definitely isn't a Hantu), it does not indicate a Jinn using its ability.

Likewise, if the breaker is on, you are in a different room than the breaker is, and more than 3m away from the breaker and the ghost is in the room with the breaker, it is not a Jinn using its ability. If, however, the ghost is in the same room as you, you are away from the breaker, and an EMF reading is left on the breaker (without changing the state of the breaker), then that would indicate a Jinn using its ability.

Comment: I noticed I forgot a detail, I updated my question with some clarification. The big issue was that the ghost room was the room with the power box, so it was realistic for the ghost to touch the door while I was within 3m of said ghost.

Comment: @TheMan if the ghost room is in the same room as the fuse box, and you are there next to the fuse box, I dont think there is anyway to distinguish between a door touch and the Jinn ability besides checking for sanity. the best way to test for this ability is either have someone check sanity if available, or by luring the ghost out of the room and seeing if it occurs. honestly though, checking for a Jinn is best done during hunts if you cant get all 3 evidence